# How to set Content-Type header for 304 http response code?

Tags: python, django

So I am using few decorators from Django to enable caching on my API:

```
@require_GET
@cache_page(100)
@cache_control(max_age=100, s_maxage=100)
@csrf_exempt
def my_api(request):
```

The problem is, 304 Not Modified response is coming back with text/html Content-Type header. My API normally returns application/json Content-Type header and I would like to be consistent. Is there a way to tell Django what content type to return with 304 response code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L411

Write a decorator to add the mimetype again

```
def RestoreMime(fn):
  def Wrapper(*args, **kwds):
    response = fn(*args, **kwds)
    response['Content-type'] = your_mime_type
    return response
  return Wrapper
```